# Swift Firebase "Cannot assign value of type 'Information' to type 'NSDictionary?'"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, segue

I have a tableview that is being populated with who a user is following. Problem is that I need to pass that cells data to "var otherUser: NSDictionary!" but because I am populating the cell using a data structure file called "Information" I get this error - "Cannot assign value of type 'Information' to type 'NSDictionary?'" in the prepareForSegue. I am unsure if I can repackage the information I need into a NSDictionary so I can successfully do a data pass. I just don't know if this is a easy solution or an actual problem because of my ignorance.

**Following TableViewController Code**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class BusinessFollowing: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var noDataView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var followingTableView: UITableView!

var yourFollowing = [Information]()

var listFollowing = [NSDictionary?]()
var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid


var loggedInUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
var loggedInUserData:NSDictionary?

var following = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.followingTableView.backgroundView = nil


}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.followingTableView.reloadData()
    self.yourFollowing.removeAll()
    self.following.removeAll()

    getFollowingData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    if segue.identifier == "following" {
        // gotta check if we're currently searching
            if let indexPath = followingTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let user = self.yourFollowing[indexPath.row]
                let controller = segue.destination as? ExploreBusinessProfileSwitchView
                controller?.otherUser = user
            }
    }
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return self.yourFollowing.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! BusinessFollowingCell
    let following = yourFollowing[indexPath.row]

    let businessName = following.businessName
    let businessStreet = following.businessStreet
    let businessCity = following.businessCity
    let businessState = following.businessState

    cell.businessName.text = businessName
    cell.businessStreet.text = businessStreet
    cell.businessCity.text = businessCity
    cell.businessState.text = businessState

    // cell.businessName?.text = self.listFollowing[indexPath.row]?["businessName"] as? String
    // cell.businessStreet?.text = self.listFollowing[indexPath.row]?["businessStreet"] as? String
    // cell.businessCity?.text = self.listFollowing[indexPath.row]?["businessCity"] as? String
    // cell.businessState?.text = self.listFollowing[indexPath.row]?["businessState"] as? String

    return cell
}

func getFollowingData() {
    self.yourFollowing.removeAll()
    self.following.removeAll()
    self.followingTableView.reloadData()

    Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!).child("following").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
            let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
            databaseRef.child("Businesses").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (usersSnapshot) in
                let users = usersSnapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                for (_, value) in users {
                    if let userID = value["uid"] as? String {
                        if userID == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                            print(value)
                            if let followingUsers = value["following"] as? [String : String] {
                                for (_,user) in followingUsers {
                                    self.following.append(user)
                                }
                            }
                            databaseRef.child("following").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (postsSnapshot) in
                                let posts = postsSnapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

                                for (_, post) in posts {
                                    for (_, postInfo) in post as! [String: AnyObject] {
                                        if let followingID = postInfo["uid"] as? String {
                                            for each in self.following {
                                                if each == followingID {
                                                    guard let uid = postInfo["uid"] as! String? else {return}
                                                    guard let name = postInfo["businessName"] as! String? else {return}
                                                    guard let address = postInfo["businessStreet"] as! String? else {return}
                                                    guard let state = postInfo["businessState"] as! String? else {return}
                                                    guard let city = postInfo["businessCity"] as! String? else {return}

                                                    self.yourFollowing.append(Information(uid: uid, businessName: name, businessStreet: address, businessCity: city, businessState: state))
                                                }

                                                self.followingTableView.backgroundView = nil
                                                self.followingTableView.reloadData()
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                            }) { (error) in
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            })
        } else {
            print("Not following anyone")
            self.followingTableView.backgroundView = self.noDataView
            MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
        }
    })

}

}
```

**"Information" Data Structure File**

```
import UIKit

class Information {

var uid: String
var businessName: String
var businessStreet: String
var businessCity: String
var businessState: String


init(uid: String, businessName: String, businessStreet: String, businessCity: String, businessState: String){

    self.uid = uid
    self.businessName = businessName
    self.businessStreet = businessStreet
    self.businessCity = businessCity
    self.businessState = businessState
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear.

`user` in `ExploreBusinessProfileSwitchView` is obviously declared as `NSDictionary`, declare it as `Information`.

By the way don't use `NSArray / NSDictionary` in Swift. Use native types.

Comment: The rest of my views sending data to that view use "var otherUser: NSDictionary!" so me changing it will solve my current problem but then create problem for the rest of my project

Comment: Also, it wouldn't be sending the correct data. When I send a "NSDictionary" over it is basically sending a whole users information from firebase. If I send over "information" it will just send 1 string and then I have to do a firebase query to pull the rest of the info for that user

Comment: I just answered the question to resolve the error. According to your code an `Information` instance contains `uid`, `name`, `address` etc., it cannot be just a string.

Comment: So if you try to use the prepareForSegue and send that indexPath.row to the NSDictionary in the next view controller, it doesn’t work. The only thing that would work in prepareForSegue is “self.yourFollowing[indexPath.row].businessName” but pushing that to the next view controller would require me to do a Firebase query call to get the rest of the data of that user. This would then mess up the entire flow of my project.

Comment: * sigh *. It's so easy. As already mentioned declare the type in the destination view controller as `Information` and pass `self.yourFollowing[indexPath.row]` (exactly this expression). And - once again – don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift anyway.

Comment: Just wondering, but why shouldn't I use NSDictionary? I am trying to become a better coder

Comment: One of the most essential features of Swift is the strong type system. `NS...` collection types however don't provide type information.